Editing Main.java
I'm new to AnyLogic and still getting familiar with the platform. I've encountered an issue that I can't seem to resolve on my own.
When I try to edit the Main.java file or any other agent's code, the editor appears to be locked, and I'm unable to make any changes. I've tested this with some of AnyLogic's example models as well, but the issue persists.
I've already tried reinstalling AnyLogic, checking file permissions, and running the software as an administrator, but nothing has worked so far.
Has anyone else experienced this issue or have any ideas on how to fix it?

You can't edit Main.java. It's locked on purpose.
That's why you have the graphical editor, you are required to use that.
Any issue you might have, can be resolved by normal means
